# How to create multiple tar files with bash script and use date as file names?

Tags: shell-script, xargs

I have a lot of files and want to create an archive for every 100 files 
i.e. the first 100 files are in one tar file, and the 101st to 200th files are in another tar file. And I want to use the date (nanoseconds) as tar names.

I have got something like this:

```
( cd "${SOURCE_DIR}" && find . -type f -name "${FILE_GLOB}" ) | 
  xargs -n 100 | xargs -I % sh -c '{tar -C "${SOURCE_DIR}" --files-from - % -cf "${DESTINATION_DIR}/$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N')-$(uname -n).tar~"}'
```

Now the problem is, the '%' in date format string will accept argument from `xargs`, which I do not want.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Sorry one more thing. what is the best way to pass SOURCE_DIR? I just found the script above does not work because SOURCE_DIR cannot be interpreted.

Comment: OK I used export command to set the variables as environment variables and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, use another symbol instead of `%`.

Use for example `-I @`. So it will be:

```
( cd "${SOURCE_DIR}" && find . -type f -name "${FILE_GLOB}" ) | 
  xargs -n 100 | xargs -I @ sh -c '{tar -C "${SOURCE_DIR}" --files-from - @ -cf "${DESTINATION_DIR}/$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N')-$(uname -n).tar~"}'
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason my mind was trapped and thought % is the only valid symbol

Comment: @Ron If this answer solved your problem, please remember to mark it as accepted and/or upvote it instead of posting a thank you comment. That is the way thanks are expressed on SE sites.